# I tried to develop the solution of this challenging integration but I never made it. Perhaps you could..

Tags: calculus

Integrating this term looked simpler but solving it stormed my mind. I found it rather difficult to integrate $\sqrt{\text{sin}x}$.
When I solve it , an infinte sequence arrived and I got trapped.

Comment: It's not nice - unless you consider elliptical functions of the first kind nice. WolframAlpha is your friend.

Comment: Sorry, I couldnot catch you.. Please elaborate.

Comment: He's telling you to look at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+\sqrt{sin%28x%29}+dx

Answer (score 0):

As somments say, the result is not very nice since it involves elliptic integrals $$\int_0^x \sqrt {\sin(t)}~dt=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^2-2 E\left(\left.\frac{1}{4}
   (\pi -2 x)\right|2\right)$$ What the comments say also is that you could try to use Wolfram Alpha or another CAS for these difficult problems.

For sure, and I suppose that this is what you tried, you could expand the integrand as an infinite series built at $t=0$ and integrate. You have $$\sqrt {\sin(t)}=\sqrt{t}-\frac{t^{5/2}}{12}+\frac{t^{9/2}}{1440}-\frac{t^{13/2}}{24192}-\frac{67
   t^{17/2}}{29030400}-\frac{t^{21/2}}{5677056}+O\left(t^{25/2}\right)$$ So $$\int_0^x \sqrt {\sin(t)}~dt=\frac{2
   t^{3/2}}{3}-\frac{t^{7/2}}{42}+\frac{t^{11/2}}{7920}-\frac{t^{15/2}}{181440}-\frac
   {67 t^{19/2}}{275788800}-\frac{t^{23/2}}{65286144}+O\left(t^{27/2}\right)$$ This leads to a very good approximation of the exact solution at least for $0\leq x\leq \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the antiderivatives of $\sin^ax$ and $\cos^ax$ cannot be expressed in terms of

elementary functions for non-integer values of *a*, can ultimately be proven using either

[Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) or the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm). As already mentioned above, one needs special

functions, such as [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), in order to do that. **However**, for the definite integral,

see [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals). We have $\displaystyle\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sin^ax~dx$ $=\dfrac{\dfrac\pi a}{B\bigg(\dfrac a2,\dfrac12\bigg)}$ , where $B(a,b)=\dfrac{\Gamma(a)\cdot\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$

is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), which extends the notion of [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), and $\Gamma(n+1)=$

$=n\cdot\Gamma(n)$ is the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), which extends the [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). In our case, for $a=\dfrac12$ , taking

into consideration the [fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function) that $\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg)=\sqrt\pi$ in conjunction with [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula),

the $($definite$)$ integral becomes $\dfrac{2\pi\sqrt{2\pi}}{\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac14\bigg)}~=~\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}\cdot\Gamma^2\bigg(\dfrac34\bigg)$. Hope this helps.